# Variable Substitution in sources.list

Tags: apt

I'm creating a local apt mirror for our VMs to utilize and would like to generic-ize the sources.list that will be deployed with the VMs.
In the Debian documentation, I found where it allows `$(ARCH)` in a sources.list line, but am wondering what other variable substitution is allowed - namely distribution (i.e. focal/jammy/etc)

Comment: First, where in the docs does it say `$(ARCH)` and secent you could make a shell script that ran at start and replaced the line. mabey put it in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/apt/sources.list.5.en.html - explicitly calls out that $(ARCH) can be used..
Since that's the only var called out there, will likely just add a substitution via ansible when the VM is provisioned and the new sources.list file is generated.